# How to get the v-ptr for a given Trait/Struct combination?

Tags: rust, trait-objects

In Rust, a `&T` where `T` is a `trait` is a fat reference, which actually corresponds to [`raw::TraitObject`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.TraitObject.html):

```
pub struct TraitObject {
    pub data: *mut (),
    pub vtable: *mut (),
}
```

Using `TraitObject`, one can de-construct and re-construct a `&T` at leisure.

However, while obtaining the `vtable` from de-constructing a `&T` is easy, what if I never have the `&T` in the first place, but just a `T` and `S`; essentially, something along the lines of:

```
fn make_vptr<T: ?Sized, S>() -> *mut ();
```

How could I divine the v-ptr from there? Is there any intrinsic I could use?

*Note: the naive implementation of creating a `S` (or conjuring it from thin-air) and then making a `&T` reference does not work; the compiler complains that `T` is not necessarily a `trait` and therefore that `&T` is either one pointer or two pointers in size.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility is to use a macro to do the magic job:

```
#![feature(raw)]

macro_rules! make_vptr(
    ($S:ty, $T:ty) => ({
        let s: &$S = unsafe { ::std::mem::uninitialized() };
        let t: &$T = s;
        let r: ::std::raw::TraitObject = unsafe { ::std::mem::transmute(t) };
        r.vtable
    })
);
```

This code will not compile if `T` is not a trait (thanks to `transmute(..)` checking that `&T` is a fat pointer) or if `T` is not implemented by `S` (thanks to the assignment).

Then, it can be used directly:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

fn main() {
    let u32_display_vtable = make_vptr!(u32, Display);

    let x = 42u32;

    let disp: &Display = unsafe {
        ::std::mem::transmute(::std::raw::TraitObject {
            data: &x as *const _ as *mut _,
            vtable: u32_display_vtable,
        })
    };

    println!("{}", disp);
}
```

Comment: Not as generic (unfortunately), as it cannot be called within a generic function, but it should be sufficient for my purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is currently possible.

In order for this to work, you'd need to be able to constrain the `T` generic parameter to *only* accept traits.  You can't do this.  As a result, it won't ever let you do anything with `&T` that depends on it being a trait, such as getting the vtable.

Comment: That is exactly what is blocking me, yes.